# Unity GUI always appearing on top another game object

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

The following question is regarding unity UI and sorting layer interaction.
I wanted to create a card game, the card game object consist of sprite and text component.

**Issue**

The problem occurs when another card game object appear on top of each other. What happen is the UI will still be appear/visible on top regardless the z position is.

[current build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwbxF.png)

**Setting**

The following is the hierarchy of the card game object

- Card Object(Game Object)

  - Card Art (Sprite/Sorting Layer: CardComponent 0)
  - Card Header (Sprite/Sorting Layer: CardComponent 2)
  - Card Tail (Sprite/Sorting Layer: CardComponent 2)
  - Card Body (Sprite/Sorting Layer: CardComponent 1)
  - Canvas (Sorting Layer: Card Component 3,Render Mode: World Space)
  - Text
  - Text

The Camera setting changes only on projection perspective only.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Is the whole card in a world space canvas? If not, you should always put the Z position at 0, or it won't make any batches. 
Then, it seems that the only element overlapping is the text, right? If so, check the text material, it might be using some overlay shader that makes it always render on top of everything.

Comment: "Is the whole card in a world space canvas?" 
I don't get the term is. Sorry
Currently canvas is under the game object. Its using world space canvas and the z position at 0.For the text material I have not added anything. When I added a "New Materials" from create new material. The text become a blob, akin to no font is selected. Do you have any suggestion for the materials?

Comment: I'm not really sure why would you have that world space canvas inside the card, can you explain it?
Are you using TextMeshPro? UGUI or World Space? Or are you using Unity Text?

Your hierarchy should be like this, with every element at Z = 0:
- Canvas (Screen Space Camera or Overlay) { Card1, Card2 }

Comment: Purpose of this, is when the card is moving, the canvas would be moving together with the card. In basic term each card would have their own canvas. Currently the canvas is using unity text

Comment: Oh, all right. It seems that is the problem then. My suggestion is that you transform all your card into UI elements, not sprites. That would make working with them far easier, if possible.
If not, you can try changing the sorting order of your world space canvas, did you try that already?

Comment: Okay will do, the current canvas sorting order is  Card Component  value in 3 (which is the largest from the rest). I guess that where there issue is. I will try change the sprite first

Comment: Have you tried changing material of your texts? It looks like your texts have shader with no z test and they are always drawn on top of all other objects